# Recursion Error while creating word cloud with pandas: Unsure how to optimize

Tags: pandas, artificial-intelligence, visualization, word-cloud

I am currently visualizing this data set [Women In Headline: bias](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/women-in-headlines-bias) and am attempting to create a world cloud using pandas

```
def WordCloud ():
  data = Train_data[Train_data['bias'] ==  5]
  text = " ".join(data["headline_no_site"])
  text = "".join(_ for _ in text if _ not in punctuation)
  text = [t.lower() for t in text.split() if t.lower() not in Woman_word and t.lower() not in stpwrds and not t.isdigit()]
  #stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
  wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
```

When I run the function I get the following error:

```
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`
```

I am worried about upping my recursion limit as my computer has difficulty in google colab already

I wasnt sure if there was to much data in the dataset (even though it was already undergon stopword removal and lemmetitzations so I tried to run it with specific data entrys but ran into the same error

I have tried different word cloud functions from other librarys however they all crashed Colab and restarted my runtime

I am unable to use a different code editor for this project

Comment: Possibly there is a space character missing in your 4th line `text = " ".join(_ for _ in text if _ not in punctuation)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work because the string gets longer by adding spaces and so python still can't process all the text before running into the recursion limit

Comment: No, the problem is that `"".join(...)`creates one long string without the necessary spaces.